# GridGain sql queries to cache of maps

Tags: gridgain

I have a `GridCache<String,Map<String,PersistentObject>` configured,

PersistentObject is interface with methods like `String getId()` and so on,
There are Entities that implements `PersistentObject`, for example `PropertyEntity` that have `name` and `value` properties and `getId()` just returns name;
key for GridCache is SimpleClassName of entities!
key for Map is String Id of entity!

is it possible to make SQL query to it like:
Select value from PropertyEntity where name=?

maybe there are another ways of organize cache?
I made map of maps because different Entity types may have same id and overwrite each other in simple map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question. Sounds like you should be able to run the query you are suggesting. Is it not working for you?

Also, it sounds like you are using an older version of GridGain. The Open Source edition of GridGain is now the [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/index.html) project. If possible, I would recommend that you upgrade.